# SQL Query on considering a like statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add a column, YES/No, based on text involved. If the Value column contains BALL, we mark it as Yes in the column. But if the 'BALL' is attached with any text/string, it should return it as 'NO'. There are some cases which I have attached

[image: Please see the example here]

How do I form the case statement so that if any text/string is attached to the 'BALL' without a space should be No, and rest all the cases should be 'Yes'. I tried using like %BALL%, but it does not satisfy all the examples in the above screenshot.

Comment: You should include the data as *text* not images.

Answer (score 1):

Just insist that the previous and next characters are not letters:

```
(case when value regexp '([^a-zA-Z]|^)BALL([a-zA-Z]|$)'
      then 'YES' else 'NO'
 end)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6d483f869dcfd614254d8babc8a5cd6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Will it satisfy the case, 9238BALL as Yes?

Comment: @AmanThakur . . . You have that as NO in your question.

Comment: I am talking about the second last case. '9238BALL' Would be Yes, and '9238BALLV' should be NO

Comment: @AmanThakur . . . This works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea8bad0dc8e337bcc8810aac6f547f2c.

Answer (score 1):

Set `@val` variable with value need to lookup:

```
SET @val := 'BALL';
```

Run query with two type of checking:

1. Use `LOCATE` to find `@val` value in the table; will return numerical position of the first character of the searched value.
2. Use `SUBSTRING` to get two sets of value from `string_val` column; using the numerical position that was obtained using `LOCATE`:

   - `val1` will return the value of `string_val` before the searched value of `@val` (the `LOCATE` result need to have a deduction of 1).
   - `val2` will return the value of `string_val` that matches `@val` and anything after it.
3. In the outer query, `chk1` checks the last character extracted to `val1` against alphabets using `REGEXP`. In this case `GOBALL` will return true (`1`) while `9232BALL` and `9232BALLV` will return false (`0`). Here we'll look at whatever false.
4. `chk2` checks if `val2` matches the searched `@val`. Therefore, the separated value of `9232BALL` which end up getting `BALL` for `val2` will return true (`1`)  while `9232BALLV` which end up getting `BALLV` for `val2` will return false (`0`). Here we'll look at whatever is true.
5. The last filter is checking the addition of `chk1+chk2`. The result we're looking for is `1` because `chk1` need to be false (`0`) and `chk2` need to be true (`1`).

```
SELECT String_val AS 'Value',
       CASE WHEN chk1+chk2=1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Yes/No'
FROM
(SELECT *,
       RIGHT(val1,1) REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]' AS chk1,
       val2=@val AS chk2
  FROM
(SELECT string_val,
        SUBSTRING(string_val,1,LOCATE(@val,string_val)-1) val1,
        SUBSTRING(string_val,LOCATE(@val,string_val)) val2
FROM mytable) A) B
```

**Alternative option 1:**

```
SELECT string_val, 
       CASE WHEN 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(CASE WHEN val1 REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]$' = 1 
                      THEN CONCAT(val1,val2) ELSE val2 END,'[0-9]','')=@Val 
       THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Yes/No'
  FROM
(SELECT string_val,
        SUBSTRING(string_val,1,LOCATE(@val,string_val)-1) val1,
        SUBSTRING(string_val,LOCATE(@val,string_val)) val2
FROM mytable) A;
```

**Alternative option 2:**

My further testing shows that it's possible to get the result using [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) with a much shorter query:

```
SET @val := 'BALL';

SELECT string_val, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_val, '[a-zA-Z]+[BALL]+[a-zA-Z]') AS vals,
      IF(((SELECT vals))=@val,'YES','NO') AS 'Yes/No'
FROM mytable;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d13a4a608e5d8cf2494619064b093b15)